# Como faço para enviar a resposta do input para o soapUI

Tags: javascript, soap

Meu código:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function valor() {
         var form1 = document.frm;
         var dados = form1.dados.value;

         if (dados == "teste"){
            alert('pegando dados');
            form1.dados.focus();
            return false;
         }

         return true;
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onSubmit="return valor()" name="frm" method="post" 
          action="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <input name="dados"  placeholder="email">
      <input type="submit" onClick="return valor()" value='Inserir texto'/>
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para enviar um envelope SOAP você teria que fazer o parser do Form para um XML valido, acho que não vale o esforço, por outro lado você pode usar o SOAPUI para fazer RESTFul MockService, você pode ler mais a respeito no seguinte link: http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/rest-service-mocking.html

Comment: sabe como fazer o soap retornar um xml ?

Comment: encontrei um plugin que faz o parse do form para SOAP, mas ainda acho mais proveitoso se trabalhar com uma API Web do que com mensagens SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você já tenha um MockService funcional no seu SOAPUI e saiba qual endereço e endpoint você precisa acessar.

neste caso você pode usar um plugin jQuery para trabalhar com mensagens SOAP:
[jQuery SOAP](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap)

A sua requisição seria algo como:

```
$.soap({
    url: '[coloque o endereço do MockService aqui]',
    method: '[Coloque a Ação a ser executada (Metodo)]',    
    data: {
        dados: "toby.mosque@contoso.com"
    },    
    success: function (soapResponse) {
        // soapResponse é a resposta SOAP.
        // você pode usar o método soapResponse.toJSON() para fazer um parse para JSON.
    },
    error: function (soapResponse) {
        // exibir erro.
    }
});
```

Comment: ok,valeu cara ajudo bastante